# Bootstrap Class col-lg... removes box-shadow

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a css class:

```
.content-shadow {
box-shadow: 0 0 5px #888888 !important;
}
```

I am using this class at to locations in the file:

```
<div class="root-content-padder">

    <div class="container">

        <h1><strong>"</strong>Die Freiarbeit ist nur das Ergebnis deiner Basis</h1>

        <div class="content-shadow">

            <div class="text-center st-padding">
                <iframe style="width: 50vw; height: 430px"
                        src="youtube.com...."></iframe>

            </div>
            <div class="text-center st-padding">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Text</button>
                <strong>Or</strong>
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Text</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 25px;"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-shadow">

                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <h1>LoL</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">

                    <p>Text</p>
                    <br/>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="?page=me">Weiter lesen</a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the first div which has the class content-shadow works fine, without a problem, but on the second one the shadow does not appear.
I can make the shadow visible on the second, if i remove the two divs `<div class="col-lg-4">...</div>` and `<div class="col-lg-8">...</div>`

That is extremely strange and i have no idea why, maybe here someone can help.
Regards Liz3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was pretty straight forward:

I had to put a `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` after the

```
 <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h1>LoL</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-8">

    <p>Text</p>
    <br/>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="?page=me">Weiter lesen</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

***If you remove any style from debugger tool, it means it comments your style at run time***.

As you are using `external style` and if you remove it from debugger tool, it comments the styles written in `content-shadow`, so where ever you have used `content-shadow` doesn't work.

But if you use `inline-style` and apply `box-shadow` in two different `div` and then remove any one of the `box-shadow` from debugger tool, it just comment your `internal-style` of that particular `div` at run-time where as another one will work

***So, it's a normal behaviour***

**Coming to your second point, `col-lg-*` removes `box-shadow`**

It is working with `col-lg-*` also as you can see the snippet. But *shadow at the bottom is not visible*, to make it visible apply `padding-bottom: 10px;` in the parent element of `content-shadow`.

```css
.content-shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px darkgreen !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="root-content-padder">

  <div class="container">

    <h1><strong>"</strong>Die Freiarbeit ist nur das Ergebnis deiner Basis</h1>

    <div class="content-shadow">

      <div class="text-center st-padding">
        <iframe style="width: 50vw; height: 230px" src="youtube.com...."></iframe>

      </div>
      <div class="text-center st-padding">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Text</button>
        <strong>Or</strong>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Text</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="height: 25px;"></div>
  <div class="container" style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <div class="content-shadow">

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <h1>LoL</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8">

        <p>Text</p>
        <br/>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg" href="?page=me">Weiter lesen</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, i edited the question, so its more clear and does not contain the error, thank you for the advice, but the original problem is still there

Comment: You should not delete the debugger tool part from question, so that in future if someone reads the ques and ans, they don't get confused. Also I have added about `col-lg-*` in my answer.

Comment: I will have a look, because the error must have a other source in the project, because its still not working

Comment: Are you not getting shadow in the second container? Anyways, take your time, check your code, we are here to help you.

Comment: Yes its not coming, but its coming when i remove the two divs with col-lg....,  checking now

Comment: Alright, seams like the col-lg is setting the actual height of the div with the class to 0 and the child div with the class col-lg.. has the height, if i manually set the height of the div with the class content-shadow it appears

Comment: [The Image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/330869117957439488/330878923959173127/Ohne_Titel_2.png)

Comment: add `z-index:1000` in the `content-shadow` css class, your grid system overlaps the shadow i think.